# MySQLfrm - Using multiple frm files

Tags: mysql, restore, mysqldump

I am busy rebuilding an entire MySQL DB. There are multiple schemas and multiple tables in each schema.

I am restoring them using *.frm files as all other methods used have either failed or corrupted the data.

I am using the command:

```
mysqlfrm --server=root:password@localhost:3306 F:\DirectoryStructure\File.frm > file.txt --diagnostic
```

Is there a way to export ALL frm files from the same command using only one command? As doing each file one by one is going to take forever. I have tried using:

```
mysqlfrm --server=root:password@localhost:3306 F:\DirectoryStructure\*.frm > filename.txt --diagnostic
```

but this doesn't work.

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use online service https://recovery.twindb.com/ (I'm the author). Basically, it's a wed interface to mysqlfrm.

To restore structure from multiple frm files you can run this

```
find /path/to/frm_files -name '*.frm' | \
xargs mysqlfrm --basedir /usr --port 3333
```

In /usr `mysqlfrm` should find `mysqld` (it starts it to read the frm).

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea why mysqlfrm can't open frm file (use --diagnostic) but service recovery.twindb.com opens it?

Comment: It's because recovery.twindb.com is awesome service! :)
Jokes aside, try to use mysqlfrm with the latest MySQL version (from 5.7.x releases)